# python run script every 2 mins, but failed

Tags: python, dataframe, schedule

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import datetime
import schedule
import time

ticks = api.ticks(api.Contracts.Stocks["2330"], "2022-08-09")
df = pd.DataFrame({**ticks})
df.ts = pd.to_datetime(df.ts)
df = df[df.volume>200]
df
```

**Above code, works fine.  I got data.**

**Below code, not working.**  I got nothing. It just keep running but no data coming.

**My goal is to run the code (receive data), every 2 mins automatically.**

I counldnt figure out where go wrong.
I would need some help.  tried many times and spent a lot of time.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import datetime
import schedule
import time

def show_datafr():
 ticks = api.ticks(api.Contracts.Stocks["2330"], "2022-08-09")
 df = pd.DataFrame({**ticks})
 df.ts = pd.to_datetime(df.ts)
 df = df[df.volume>200]
 df
 
schedule.every(4).seconds.do(show_datafr)

while 1:
 schedule.run_pending()
 time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: entering the name of the value works only on console. You need `print(df)` instead of `df` only

Answer (score 0):

if you want to run every 2 min, the schedule line is quite strange.
it should be:
schedule.every(2).minutes.do(show_datafr)

instead of:

schedule.every(4).seconds.do(show_datafr)

as what you wrote is to run every 4 sec, and possibly the operation cannot be finished in 4 sec, causing it no output

Comment: Sorry It was my mistake.  I forget to change the time back.  I tried many variable, 2 mins, 1 mins, but failed.

Comment: I just used this sample code to test and it gave me the correct output:
def show_datafr():
    print('hi')
 
schedule.every(1).minutes.do(show_datafr)

while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)

which means the code is correct. you can test how much time your "show_datafr" function consumes. if it's roughly over 2min, it makes sense that it will give no output

Comment: ji chen, thanks for helping me out.  Much Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To display **df** you can import **display** from **IPython.display**

You might want to install it with `pip install ipython` incase you don't have it installed.

```py
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import datetime
from schedule
import time
from IPython.display import display     # Additional import


def show_datafr():
    ticks = api.ticks(api.Contracts.Stocks["2330"], "2022-08-09")
    df = pd.DataFrame({**ticks})
    df.ts = pd.to_datetime(df.ts)
    df = df[df.volume>200]

    display(df)  # To display dataframe


schedule.every(2).minutes.do(show_datafr)  # Remember you said every 2 minutes
    
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Magic..  It works well.  thanks.  Much apprciated..

Comment: How could I possibly have the column value colored??
df.style.applymap(lambda x: "background-color: green" if x == "Low" else "background-color: red" if x == "High" else "background-color: black")
this line works ok.  if it is not in schedule mode.  where can i put it??

Comment: I post a new question that might be easier to understand.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73334340/python-df-style-applymap-not-wok-in-schedule-mode

Comment: You are welcome  @Divid Lin...  I guess  one of your conditions is not properly stated, change  the second  `if` to `elif` and try again  to see if that works.