# Python df.style.applymap not wok in schedule mode

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import datetime
import schedule
import time

ticks = api.ticks(api.Contracts.Stocks["2330"], "2022-08-12")
df = pd.DataFrame({**ticks})
df.ts = pd.to_datetime(df.ts)
df['成交時間'] = df['ts'].dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S') #調整格式式
df['ask_price'] = df['ask_price'].map('${:,.1f}'.format) #調整格式式
df['close'] = df['close'].map('${:,.1f}'.format) #調整格式式
df['bid_price'] = df['bid_price'].map('${:,.1f}'.format) #調整格式式
df = df.drop(["ts"], axis=1) #取消不需要欄位_tick_type
df = df.drop(["tick_type"], axis=1) #取消不需要欄位_tick_type
df = df.drop(["ask_volume"], axis=1) #取消不需要欄位_ask_volume
df = df.drop(["bid_volume"], axis=1) #取消不需要欄位_bid_volume
df = df[df.volume>200]
conditions = [df["close"] == df["ask_price"]] #條件:收盤等於外盤
choices = ['外盤']
df['外盤'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='-')
conditions = [df["close"] == df["bid_price"]] #條件:收盤等於內盤
choices = ['內盤']
df['內盤'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='-')
df = df[['成交時間', 'ask_price', 'close', 'bid_price', 'volume','外盤','內盤']] #欄位指定順序
df = df.sort_values(["成交時間"], ascending=False) #依時間欄排序, 近的在上, 遠的在下
df.style.applymap(lambda x: "background-color: green" if x == "內盤" else "background-color: red" if x == "外盤" else "background-color: black")
```

Above code, runs well.

Below code, runs well too.  runs every 20 seconds repeatly.  Thanks for helping.
however, it does not colored the cell.

```
df.style.applymap(lambda x: "background-color: green" if x == "內盤" else "background-color: red" if x == "外盤" else "background-color: black")
```

this particular code, doesnt work here, but works well on above code.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import datetime
import schedule
import time
from IPython.display import display     # Additional import

def show_datafr():
    ticks = api.ticks(api.Contracts.Stocks["2330"], "2022-08-12")
    df = pd.DataFrame({**ticks})
    df.ts = pd.to_datetime(df.ts)
    df['成交時間'] = df['ts'].dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S') #調整格式式
    df['ask_price'] = df['ask_price'].map('${:,.1f}'.format) #調整格式式
    df['close'] = df['close'].map('${:,.1f}'.format) #調整格式式
    df['bid_price'] = df['bid_price'].map('${:,.1f}'.format) #調整格式式
    df = df.drop(["ts"], axis=1) #取消不需要欄位_tick_type
    df = df.drop(["tick_type"], axis=1) #取消不需要欄位_tick_type
    df = df.drop(["ask_volume"], axis=1) #取消不需要欄位_ask_volume
    df = df.drop(["bid_volume"], axis=1) #取消不需要欄位_bid_volume
    df = df[df.volume>200]    

    conditions = [df["close"] == df["ask_price"]] #條件:收盤等於外盤
    choices = ['外盤']
    df['外盤'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='-')

    conditions = [df["close"] == df["bid_price"]] #條件:收盤等於內盤
    choices = ['內盤']
    df['內盤'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='-')

    df = df[['成交時間', 'ask_price', 'close', 'bid_price', 'volume','外盤','內盤']] #欄位指定順序
    df = df.sort_values(["成交時間"], ascending=False) #依時間欄排序, 近的在上, 遠的在下
    df.style.applymap(lambda x: "background-color: green" if x == "內盤" else "background-color: red" if x == "外盤" else "background-color: black")
    display(df)  # To display dataframe
    
schedule.every(20).seconds.do(show_datafr)  
    
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

**Many thanks.  I really appreciated.**
Revised, I found the solution.
by replace display(df) with below.

```
display(df.style.applymap(lambda x: "background-color: green" if x == "內盤" else "background-color: red" if x == "外盤" else "background-color: black"))
```

Comment: I found the solution.
df.style.applymap(lambda x: "background-color: green" if x == "內盤" else "background-color: red" if x == "外盤" else "background-color: black")

Comment: Oh ok you got it already,  I letf  a comment on your previous question as well.